# How to Integrate MySql tables Data To Ksql Stream or Tables?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am trying to build a data pipeline from **MySql** to **Ksql**.

Use Case: data source is MySql. I have created a table in MySql.

I am using

```
./bin/connect-standalone ./etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties  ./etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-quickstart-sqlite.properties
```

to start a standalone connector. And it is working fine.

I am starting the consumer with topic name i.e.

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test1Category --from-beginning
```

when I am inserting the data in MySQL table I am getting the result in consumer as well. **I have created KSQL Stream as will with the same topic name**. I am expecting the same result in my Kstream as well, But i am not getting any result when i am doing

```
select * from <streamName>
```

**Connector configuration--source-quickstart-mysql.properties**

```
    name=jdbc_source_mysql
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector

key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081

value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081

connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB?user=root&password=cloudera

#comment=Which table(s) to include
table.whitelist=ftest

mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=id

topic.prefix=ftopic
```

**Sample Data**

- **MySql**

1.) Create Database:

```
CREATE DATABASE testDB;
```

2.) Use Database:

```
USE testDB;
```

3.) create the table:

```
    CREATE TABLE products (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(512),
  weight FLOAT
);
```

4.) Insert data into the table:

```
    INSERT INTO products(id,name,description,weight)
  VALUES (103,'car','Small car',20);
```

- **KSQL**

1.) Create Stream:

```
CREATE STREAM pro_original (id int, name varchar, description varchar,weight bigint) WITH \
(kafka_topic='proproducts', value_format='DELIMITED');
```

2.) Select Query:

```
Select * from pro_original;
```

**Expected Output**

1. **Consumer**

getting the data which is inserted in the MySQL table.

Here I am getting the data in MySQL.

2. **Ksql**

In-Stream data should be populated which is inserted in Mysql table and reflecting in Kafka topic.

**I am not getting expected result in ksql**

Help me for this data pipeline.

Comment: How did you create your stream? Also, it would be useful if you share some sample data.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous  I have mentioned all the sample data which i am using to create MySQL table and Kstream. I am getting the result in Kafka consumer but it is not reflecting in stream

Comment: Can you post your connector's configuration as well? It would be useful in order to check the format of your values.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I have added the source-quickstart-mysql.properties configuration. please check. If you need any more details let me know

Comment: See my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: I would suggest starting the select query, and then inserting data. But the JDBC Kafka Connectors don't produce delimited data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is in AVRO format but in the `VALUE_FORMAT` instead of `AVRO` you've defined `DELIMITED`. It is important to instruct KSQL the format of the values that are stored in the topic. The following should do the trick for you.

```
CREATE STREAM pro_original_v2 \ 
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='products', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

Data inserted into kafka topic **after** executing

```
SELECT * FROM pro_original_v2;
```

should now be visible in your ksql console window.

You can have a look at some Avro examples in KSQL [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/installation/server-config/avro-schema.html#using-avro-in-ksql).

Comment: Thanks @GiorgosMyrianthous above solution is solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: @cricket_007 could you suggest me the good tutorial to learn Kafka+Confluent ecosystem